# How to update a plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm having issues with redrawing the figure here. I allow the user to specify the units in the time scale (x-axis) and then I recalculate and call this function `plots()`. I want the plot to simply update, not append another plot to the figure.

```
def plots():
    global vlgaBuffSorted
    cntr()

    result = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for d in vlgaBuffSorted:
        result[d['event']].append(d)

    result_list = result.values()

    f = Figure()
    graph1 = f.add_subplot(211)
    graph2 = f.add_subplot(212,sharex=graph1)

    for item in result_list:
        tL = []
        vgsL = []
        vdsL = []
        isubL = []
        for dict in item:
            tL.append(dict['time'])
            vgsL.append(dict['vgs'])
            vdsL.append(dict['vds'])
            isubL.append(dict['isub'])
        graph1.plot(tL,vdsL,'bo',label='a')
        graph1.plot(tL,vgsL,'rp',label='b')
        graph2.plot(tL,isubL,'b-',label='c')

    plotCanvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, pltFrame)
    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(plotCanvas, pltFrame)
    toolbar.pack(side=BOTTOM)
    plotCanvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [real-time plotting in while loop with matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874767/real-time-plotting-in-while-loop-with-matplotlib)

Comment: figure.canvas.draw_idle() to force your plot to appear on screen if it does not.

Answer (score 248, accepted):

You essentially have two options:

1. Do exactly what you're currently doing, but call `graph1.clear()` and `graph2.clear()` before replotting the data.  This is the slowest, but most simplest and most robust option.
2. Instead of replotting, you can just update the data of the plot objects.  You'll need to make some changes in your code, but this should be much, much faster than replotting things every time.  However, the shape of the data that you're plotting can't change, and if the range of your data is changing, you'll need to manually reset the x and y axis limits.

To give an example of the second option:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 6*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

# You probably won't need this if you're embedding things in a tkinter plot...
plt.ion()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
line1, = ax.plot(x, y, 'r-') # Returns a tuple of line objects, thus the comma

for phase in np.linspace(0, 10*np.pi, 500):
    line1.set_ydata(np.sin(x + phase))
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
```

Comment: I tried testing "1." and the result was, after I replotted the data another set of plots were drawn in my GUI, so now I had 4 plots after recalculation, just like before.

Comment: @thenickname - Where exactly in your code are you calling `clear`?  You should be calling `graph1.clear(); graph2.clear()` inside your `for` loop, just before you call `graph1.plot(...)`, `graph2.plot(...)` etc...

Comment: That for loop creates calles graphx.plot(...) N times and putting the clear statements in there only plots the last one. I've actually pulled out the canvas code and put it into the main program loop along with the figure code and I now have my function being called by a button. For some reason if I just call the function the plots get updated, but if I press the button the plots do not. It's pretty interesting behavior. I think that must be a bug in Tkinter.

Comment: Just a hunch... Are you missing a call `fig.canvas.draw()` or `plt.draw()` after plotting each frame?  (I.e. you should have a sequence of `clear`, `plot`, `draw` each time you want to show a frame) I'm guessing, but I think that would cause exactly the behavior you're describing... Good luck, at any rate!

Comment: It's 2k14 and I stumbled to achieve something like this... it works as expected but the plotting window is turning "not responding" .. any suggestions??

Comment: there doesn't seem to be a `set_data` for `scatter`.  is there a way to update scatter plots?  especially a way to update their position and colors?

Comment: I seem to be getting a "not implemented error"  at  `fig.canvas.flush_events()`. Any one know what the reason could be?

Comment: in 2020 with mpl 3.3.1 this does not work unfortunately. Can it be dependend on the backend?

Comment: When I use the 2nd option with set_ydata it works but it leaves the old line, although the old line is with `linewidth=1` when the `line1` is specified with  `linewidth=2`.`

Answer (score 60):

You can also do like the following:
This will draw a 10x1 random matrix data on the plot for 50 cycles of the for loop.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.ion()
for i in range(50):
    y = np.random.random([10,1])
    plt.plot(y)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.0001)
    plt.clf()
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to output a graph. Am I missing something? I have `%matplotlib inline` in Jupyter notebook as well.

Comment: haha, worked for me when I removed the `plt.clf()`.  Oh `matplotlib`, you rascal :)

Comment: But this is not updating ONE plot! It draws 50 plots!

Comment: This did not answer the question and just plotted and cleared 50 times instead. Be warned!

Comment: You are clearly plotting 50 time in a loop with clearing figure each time. This is very slow.

Answer (score 23):

This worked for me:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import clear_output
import numpy as np
for i in range(50):
    clear_output(wait=True)
    y = np.random.random([10,1])
    plt.plot(y)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: It only works on Jupyter notebook

Answer (score 20):

This worked for me. Repeatedly calls a function updating the graph every time.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as anim

def plot_cont(fun, xmax):
    y = []
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

    def update(i):
        yi = fun()
        y.append(yi)
        x = range(len(y))
        ax.clear()
        ax.plot(x, y)
        print i, ': ', yi

    a = anim.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=xmax, repeat=False)
    plt.show()
```

"fun" is a function that returns an integer.
FuncAnimation will repeatedly call "update", it will do that "xmax" times.

Comment: Could you give an example on how you call this  function (especially how you pass a function in a function call) as well as how the fun() function looks like?

Comment: Sure. "fun()" is any function that returns an integer. You can pass the function as an argument to another like this: "plot_cont(my_function, 123)".

There you have me calling plot_cont at line 86:
https://github.com/vitobasso/audio-ml/blob/bbb3f633ef3638406912d6f75a8c6a7311aea3fc/src/train_spec.py

Comment: Note that "a = " is necessary or FuncAnimation will be garbage collected and the code won't work!

Answer (score 9):

I have released a package called [python-drawnow](https://github.com/scottsievert/python-drawnow) that provides functionality to let a figure update, typically called within a for loop, similar to Matlab's `drawnow`.

An example usage:

```
from pylab import figure, plot, ion, linspace, arange, sin, pi
def draw_fig():
    # can be arbitrarily complex; just to draw a figure
    #figure() # don't call!
    plot(t, x)
    #show() # don't call!

N = 1e3
figure() # call here instead!
ion()    # enable interactivity
t = linspace(0, 2*pi, num=N)
for i in arange(100):
    x = sin(2 * pi * i**2 * t / 100.0)
    drawnow(draw_fig)
```

This package works with any matplotlib figure and provides options to wait after each figure update or drop into the debugger.

Answer (score 8):

In case anyone comes across this article looking for what I was looking for, I found examples at

[How to visualize scalar 2D data with Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127668/how-to-visualize-scalar-2d-data-with-matplotlib/10252292#10252292)

and

[http://mri.brechmos.org/2009/07/automatically-update-a-figure-in-a-loop
 (on web.archive.org)](http://web.archive.org/web/20130114230355/http://mri.brechmos.org/2009/07/automatically-update-a-figure-in-a-loop)

then modified them to use imshow with an input stack of frames, instead of generating and using contours on the fly.

---

Starting with a 3D array of images of shape (nBins, nBins, nBins), called `frames`.

```
def animate_frames(frames):
    nBins   = frames.shape[0]
    frame   = frames[0]
    tempCS1 = plt.imshow(frame, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
    for k in range(nBins):
        frame   = frames[k]
        tempCS1 = plt.imshow(frame, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
        del tempCS1
        fig.canvas.draw()
        #time.sleep(1e-2) #unnecessary, but useful
        fig.clf()

fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)

win = fig.canvas.manager.window
fig.canvas.manager.window.after(100, animate_frames, frames)
```

I also found a much simpler way to go about this whole process, albeit less robust:

```
fig = plt.figure()

for k in range(nBins):
    plt.clf()
    plt.imshow(frames[k],cmap=plt.cm.gray)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    time.sleep(1e-6) #unnecessary, but useful
```

Note that both of these only seem to work with `ipython --pylab=tk`, a.k.a.`backend = TkAgg`

Thank you for the help with everything.

Answer (score 4):

All of the above might be true, however for me "online-updating" of figures only works with some backends, specifically `wx`. You just might try to change to this, e.g. by starting ipython/pylab by `ipython --pylab=wx`! Good luck!

Comment: None of the other answers helped in my case. I am using pycharm and the problem was with plotting and interactivity of the console. I needed to add    From pylab import * and then ion() in the code body to turn interactive on. It works smoothly now for me.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the other answers, I wrapped the figure's update in a python decorator to separate the plot's update mechanism from the actual plot. This way, it is much easier to update any plot.

```
def plotlive(func):
    plt.ion()

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def new_func(*args, **kwargs):

        # Clear all axes in the current figure.
        axes = plt.gcf().get_axes()
        for axis in axes:
            axis.cla()

        # Call func to plot something
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)

        # Draw the plot
        plt.draw()
        plt.pause(0.01)

        return result

    return new_func
```

### Usage example

And then you can use it like any other decorator.

```
@plotlive
def plot_something_live(ax, x, y):
    ax.plot(x, y)
    ax.set_ylim([0, 100])
```

The only constraint is that you have to create the figure before the loop:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(100):
    x = np.arange(100)
    y = np.full([100], fill_value=i)
    plot_something_live(ax, x, y)
```