# How do I display real-time graphs in a simple UI for a python program?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, vispy

I have a complicated algorithm that updates 3 histograms that are stored in arrays.  I want to debug my algorithm, so I was thinking of showing the arrays as histograms in a user interface.  What is the easiest way to do this.  (Rapid application development is more important than optimized code.)

I have some experience with Qt (in C++) and some experience with matplotlib.

(I'm going to leave this question open for a day or two because it's hard for me to evaluate the solutions without a lot more experience that I don't have.  Hopefully, the community's votes will help choose the best answer.)

Comment: If rapid development is what you're after, I'd recommend Tkinter. It's far more intuitive IMO than PyQt.

Comment: I don't see the difficulty. Just use matplotlib to plot the histograms. Any particular issue?

Comment: @Bernardo, I want them to update as the underlying data structures are updated.  If I plot using matplotlib, I'll get a graph for every time step?  That is going to be hard to keep track of when I have a window for every time step.

Comment: @Neil: There is an example of making an animated graph here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098131/matplotlib-update-a-plot/4098938#4098938 . Perhaps that will help you?

Comment: @unutbu nice +1, why didn't you put as an answer?

Comment: @Bernardo: It's Joe Kington's answer, so he deserves the credit :)

Comment: @unutbu Please add it as he's not here to add it.  Anyway, you deserve the credit for reading the question and making the connection.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Edit: Nowadays, it is easier and better to use `matplotlib.animation`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation


def animate(frameno):
    x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(10000)
    n, _ = np.histogram(x, bins, normed=True)
    for rect, h in zip(patches, n):
        rect.set_height(h)
    return patches    

mu, sigma = 100, 15
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(10000)
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, 50, normed=1, facecolor='green', alpha=0.75)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, blit=True, interval=10,
                              repeat=True)
plt.show()
```

---

There is an example of making an animated graph [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098131/matplotlib-update-a-plot/4098938#4098938).
Building on this example, you might try something like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion()
mu, sigma = 100, 15
fig = plt.figure()
x = mu + sigma*np.random.randn(10000)
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, 50, normed=1, facecolor='green', alpha=0.75)
for i in range(50):
    x = mu + sigma*np.random.randn(10000)
    n, bins = np.histogram(x, bins, normed=True)
    for rect,h in zip(patches,n):
        rect.set_height(h)
    fig.canvas.draw()
```

I can get about 14 frames per second this way, compared to 4 frames per second using the code I [first posted](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8feecf2d-3288-40b5-b437-2c31636814e6/view-source). The trick is to avoid asking matplotlib to draw complete figures. Instead call `plt.hist` once, then manipulate the existing `matplotlib.patches.Rectangle`s in `patches` to update the histogram, and call
`fig.canvas.draw()` to make the updates visible.

Comment: This works well but the plotting window turns not responding or closes on its own.. any suggestion?

Comment: @DevC: Nowadays, it is better to use `matplotlib.animation`. I've added an example, above.

Comment: Here you can find example animation videos: http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/

Comment: how is this done with real time emotion detection using webcam with opencv python?

Answer (score 13):

For realtime plotting, I recommend trying Chaco, pyqtgraph, or any of the opengl-based libraries like glumpy or visvis. Matplotlib, wonderful as it is, is generally not suitable for this kind of application.

**Edit:** the developers of glumpy, visvis, galry, and pyqtgraph are all collaborating on a visualization library called [vispy](http://vispy.org/). It is still early in development, but promising and already quite powerful.

Comment: The [vispy website](http://vispy.org) includes a gallery of several applications and the code corresponding to these applications.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using matplotlib in interactive mode, if you call `.show` once then it will pop up in its own window, if you don't then it exists only in memory and can be written to a file when you're done with it.

Answer (score 0):

Ouh, now see, when you say real time you mean you want a refresh rate higher than 5 Hz matplotlib won't do the job. I had this problem before, I went for [PyQwt](http://pyqwt.sourceforge.net/) that works with PyQt.

Comment: PyQwt is currently considered unmaintained. Hopefully that will change in the future, but beware for now..