# how to create a changing plot in qtgui

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I want to add a plot in a QtGui application that changes, ie it first shows one point, then 2 then 3 etc, or you can think of it as a moving window, ie you have 100 points but you first display the first 10 points then you drop the first point shift the 9 points and add a new point etc.

I've gotten as far as plotting points, I was just curious about whether I should be just trying to update the plot, or should I use something like QGraphicsScene. To me this seems like overkill but thought I'd ask.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found info in these topics

[How do I display real-time graphs in a simple UI for a python program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129697/how-do-i-display-real-time-graphs-in-a-simple-ui-for-a-python-program#)

[How to update a plot in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098131/matplotlib-update-a-plot/4098938#)

I'll assume that given they didn't use QGRaphicsScene that is the right way to go, ie not using it.