# Iinteractive real time plotting in python/pyqt

Tags: python, qt, real-time

I'm trying to implement an application that plots data in a real time fashion. I have tried some code I found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129697/how-do-i-display-real-time-graphs-in-a-simple-ui-for-a-python-program) but it doesn't work. The figure plots one result before the `for` loop and one result when the `for` loop is done

This is run in Ubuntu, from the Python interpreter.

The code I'm referring to:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion()
mu, sigma = 100, 15
fig = plt.figure()
x = mu + sigma*np.random.randn(10000)
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, 50, normed=1, facecolor='green', alpha=0.75)
for i in range(50):
    x = mu + sigma*np.random.randn(10000)
    n, bins = np.histogram(x, bins, normed=True)
    for rect,h in zip(patches,n):
        rect.set_height(h)
    fig.canvas.draw()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arises because of the backend. I had `Qt4Agg` and after changing it to `TkAgg` it worked.. no idea why Qt4Agg didn't worth though...

to change the backend i had to edit the /etc/matplotlibrc file

EDIT:

found information about Qt4Agg instead of calling `draw()` it should be paused for as long as required by calling `pause(0.001)` instead, here it is paused for 1ms.

info on this

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/177