# Continuous 3D plotting (i.e. figure update)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, matplotlib-3d

I have a simulation which calculates surface data for each iteration of the simulation.
I would like to continuously plot that data as a surface plot to the same window (updating the plot in each iteration) in order to see how it evolves and to check the algorithm.

My Idea was to create a class that would initialize the window/plot and then redraw to that window from inside the simulation loop. Here is the class I came up with:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FixedLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import matplotlib
matplotlib.interactive( False )

class plot3dClass( object ):

    def __init__( self, systemSideLength, lowerCutoffLength ):
        self.systemSideLength = systemSideLength
        self.lowerCutoffLength = lowerCutoffLength
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot( 111, projection='3d' )
        self.ax.set_zlim3d( -10e-9, 10e9 )

        X = np.arange( 0, self.systemSideLength, self.lowerCutoffLength )
        Y = X
        self.X, self.Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

        self.ax.w_zaxis.set_major_locator( LinearLocator( 10 ) )
        self.ax.w_zaxis.set_major_formatter( FormatStrFormatter( '%.03f' ) )

        heightR = np.zeros( self.X.shape )
        self.surf = self.ax.plot_surface( self.X, self.Y, heightR, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0, antialiased=False )
        #~ self.fig.colorbar( self.surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5 )

        plt.show()


    def drawNow( self, heightR ):

        self.surf = self.ax.plot_surface( self.X, self.Y, heightR, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0, antialiased=False )
        plt.draw()                      # redraw the canvas

        time.sleep(1)
```

The problem I have with this code, is that the code stops at the 'plt.show()' and only continues, when I close the plot-window. Also I am not sure if the calls of 'self.ax.plot_surface( ... )' and 'plt.draw()' would update the figure as I would like it.

So is this class the right direction?

If yes: What modifications are needed?

If not: Could somebody please give me advice how to achieve what I want?

I realize that this problem might seem trivial to others, but I (honestly) did spend the whole day yesterday on Google and trying and I'm at a loss...

Any help would greatly appreciated, so that I can get back to my actual work.

Tanks alot in advance.

As a reference:

I also found the following code which does, what I want, but it is in 2D, so it does not help me directly:

```
from pylab import *
import time

ion()

tstart = time.time()               # for profiling
x = arange(0,2*pi,0.01)            # x-array
line, = plot(x,sin(x))

for i in arange(1,200):
    line.set_ydata(sin(x+i/10.0))  # update the data
    draw()                         # redraw the canvas

print 'FPS:' , 200/(time.time()-tstart)
```

Answer (score 9):

You do not need to `plt.show()` if it is an animated (interactive) plot.  You also want interactive set to True, not False which is the same as calling `ion()` in your 2d example.  Also, you need to `remove()` the surface plots from previous frames if you do not want to see them all.

Otherwise you were pretty close.

This works for me:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FixedLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import matplotlib, time

class plot3dClass( object ):

    def __init__( self, systemSideLength, lowerCutoffLength ):
        self.systemSideLength = systemSideLength
        self.lowerCutoffLength = lowerCutoffLength
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot( 111, projection='3d' )
        self.ax.set_zlim3d( -10e-9, 10e9 )

        rng = np.arange( 0, self.systemSideLength, self.lowerCutoffLength )
        self.X, self.Y = np.meshgrid(rng,rng)

        self.ax.w_zaxis.set_major_locator( LinearLocator( 10 ) )
        self.ax.w_zaxis.set_major_formatter( FormatStrFormatter( '%.03f' ) )

        heightR = np.zeros( self.X.shape )
        self.surf = self.ax.plot_surface( 
            self.X, self.Y, heightR, rstride=1, cstride=1, 
            cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0, antialiased=False )
        # plt.draw() maybe you want to see this frame?

    def drawNow( self, heightR ):
        self.surf.remove()
        self.surf = self.ax.plot_surface( 
            self.X, self.Y, heightR, rstride=1, cstride=1, 
            cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0, antialiased=False )
        plt.draw()                      # redraw the canvas
        time.sleep(1)

matplotlib.interactive(True)

p = plot3dClass(5,1)
for i in range(2):
    p.drawNow(np.random.random(p.X.shape))
```

Comment: this doesn't work on my computer (Win XP, python 2.7.3): all I see is the final graph

Comment: It needs self.fig.canvas.flush_events() after the plt.draw() line. (credit http://stackoverflow.com/a/4098938/415551)

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem and this worked for me:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

for k in xrange(0,X_range):
    ax.plot(x_input, y_input, z_input)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.02)
    ax.cla()
```

For you, I'd imagine the solution be something similar to [the top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5185453/6122008) except replacing `time.sleep()` with `plt.pause()`, which would finish the drawing the figure before sleeping.

Answer (score 2):

I am grateful for the answer from Paul, although I haven't to tried it out yet.

In the meantime I had found another solution that works and renders with OpenGL using MayaVI, which is OK as I only need real-time quick visual feedback. However I had to install the following packages under Ubuntu: python-enthoughtbase and mayavi2

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import time
from enthought.mayavi import mlab
from enthought.tvtk.tools import visual

    class plot3dClass( object ):

        def __init__( self, systemSideLength, lowerCutoffLength ):
            self.systemSideLength = systemSideLength
            self.lowerCutoffLength = lowerCutoffLength

            rangeMax = self.systemSideLength
            X = np.arange( 0, self.systemSideLength, self.lowerCutoffLength )
            Y = X

            matrixSize = int( round( self.systemSideLength / self.lowerCutoffLength ) )
            heightR = np.zeros( ( matrixSize, matrixSize ) )

            fig = mlab.figure(size=(500,500))
            visual.set_viewer(fig)
            self.surf = mlab.surf( X, Y, heightR, warp_scale = 1e1 ) # NOTE: the warp_scale factor is relative to the scale of the x- and y-axes
            box_extent = ( 0,rangeMax, 0,rangeMax, -1e-7,1e-7 ) # NOTE: the extent options refers to the size and position in the 3D space relative to the origin

            mlab.outline(self.surf, color=(0.7, .7, .7), extent = box_extent )

        def drawNow( self, heightR ):
            self.surf.mlab_source.scalars = heightR
            time.sleep(0.033)
```

This class is not quite where I would like it to be and I have two immediate issues with it:

1. After a short will the window is grayed by Ubuntu as (I suppose) Ubuntu thinks the application is not responding. Perhaps rather a an Ubuntu issue, but annoying.
2. I have been trying to find out how I can be able to rotate the plot with the mouse while animating.

I will try getting these answered in another thread.

**EDIT:**
Ok. I have just tried the code as suggested by Paul and it also works for me. However, trying it I have become aware that MatPlotLib probably is not the best choice for doing animations in real-time. At least for me it is extremely slow (perhaps only in 3D?).

So in the end I will stick with the MayaVI implementation from above, which except for the two points mentioned, works great.

**EDIT:** If you go with the MatPlotLib solution, I have found that you can put the line `matplotlib.interactive(True)` inside the declaration of the plotting class. That way you can have MatPlotLib only defined within the plotting class.

Comment: you are not giving a useful answer to yourself. The OP title was: How to achieve continuous 3D plotting (i.e. update a figure) using Python and **MatPlotLib**?. And you give to yourself and answer that uses MayaVI instead of matplotlib. On the other hand, you got a valid answer using matplotlib and you did not tried it first thing...