# Python- 1 second plots continous presentation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dictionary with data. For every entry I would like to display plots for 1 second and move to the next one. The plots to display are already coded in external scripts. I would like to do this automatically. So I loop through the dict, display first set of plots[0], close the plots[0], display plots[1] close plots[1] ... I would like to set up display time for let say 1 second and have the plot as full screen. The problem that during the presentation I don't want to touch the computer.

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-np.pi, np.pi, 0.1)         # only for the example purpose
myDict = {"sin":np.sin(x), "cos":np.cos(x), "exp":np.exp(x)}
for key in myDict:
    print myDict[key]
    pl.plt.plot(myDict[key])              # in origin coming from external function
    pl.plt.plot(x)                        # in origin coming from external function
    pl.plt.show()
```

Does anyone know what function should be used and how to modify above?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179589/how-to-achieve-continuous-3d-plotting-i-e-update-a-figure-using-python-and-ma

Comment: possible duplicate of [pylab.ion() in python 2, matplotlib 1.1.1 and updating of the plot while the program runs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12822762/pylab-ion-in-python-2-matplotlib-1-1-1-and-updating-of-the-plot-while-the-pro)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple method is to use `plt.pause(1)`.  A more sophisticated method is to usethe `matplotlib.animate` module.  See [pylab.ion() in python 2, matplotlib 1.1.1 and updating of the plot while the program runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12822762/pylab-ion-in-python-2-matplotlib-1-1-1-and-updating-of-the-plot-while-the-pro/12826273#12826273)

[example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/dynamic_image.html), [api](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html), [tutorial](http://jakevdp.github.com/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

pl.ion()
x = np.arange(-np.pi, np.pi, 0.1)         # only for the example purpose
myDict = {"sin":np.sin, "cos":np.cos, "exp":np.exp}
for key in myDict:
    print myDict[key]
    pl.clf()
    y = myDict[key](x)
    pl.plt.plot(x, y, label=key)
    pl.plt.draw()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: @Lepy I try to implement your solution but it doesn't want to work. I cannot change lines `pl.plt.plot(myDict[key])` and `pl.plt.plot(x)` as in the original problem they are implemented in different script. When I try as it stands, the figure does not show I try different things but now lack. How would you write with multpiple `plot()` functions to display on one figure? And also do you know how to have the figure in the whole screen?