# matplotlib plotting... running code line by line vs in one chunk (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was practicing plotting in matplotlib, and I noticed that the following code works correctly when I run it as one big chunk, but not when I enter it line by line into the console (a blank figure window shows up, but the line does not).  What gives?

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
fig,axes=plt.subplots()
axes.plot([1,2,3],[2,3,4])
plt.show()
```

I'm running Enthought Canopy, Python 2.7.6., matplotlib 1.3.1

Thanks!

P.S. What I find even stranger is if I subsequently type `fig` into the console, all of a sudden the correct plot pops up in the figure window.

Comment: plot at once or line by line interactively?

Comment: What does `big chunk` mean? Dose each line have a sample?

Comment: Big chunk means I copy and paste the entire code segment into the console, vs pasting in each line separately.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12822762/pylab-ion-in-python-2-matplotlib-1-1-1-and-updating-of-the-plot-while-the-pro) helps

Comment: And you need to clarify your question to get an answer. We should guess... what you ask.