# Matplotlib draw to plot within function immediately

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there any way to draw to a plot within a function and then have the changes show up on the plot before the function is finished executing?

For instance, in this function I would like to get the window extent of the text, but the function gives the error `Cannot get window extent w/o renderer`
 because at the time `s.get_window_extent()` is called the text has not been drawn on the plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
plt.ion()
myfig, myax = plt.subplots()


def plot_now():
    s = myax.annotate("foo", [0.5, 0.5])
    myfig.canvas.draw_idle()
    s.get_window_extent()

plot_now()
```

I'm using iPython, python 2.7.6, matplotlib 1.4.3, and the Qt4Agg backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `plt.draw()` before it goes sleep.

Comment: Does not work - the figure doesn't update until the function is done running

Comment: It worked on my end running on 2.7.6 shell and matplotlib version 1.3.1

Comment: Well, that's quite the mystery then. I wonder why it works for you but not for me, what version of MPL are you running?

Comment: Update: This does actually work, the problem I was having was with time.sleep(), which I don't actually need. It works with new example I put up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try `plt.pause(60)` instead of `time.sleep(60)`. Someone answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12822762/pylab-ion-in-python-2-matplotlib-1-1-1-and-updating-of-the-plot-while-the-pro) says that `time.sleep` doesn't work with Qt4Agg.

Comment: I was actually just using time.sleep() for demonstration purposes, it's not actually in my real code. I've updated my example to be closer to my actual problem