# plt.plot() Not Displaying Points dynamically

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

This is a simplified version of my code. Basically, I want to plot points dynamically, but I want it to be like a line plot, not scatter. I don't know why this code works:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

for i in range(10):
    
    x = i
    y = np.random.randint(1,11)
    
    plt.scatter(x,y)
    plt.pause(0.05)
    
    
plt.show()
```

but as soon as I change `plt.scatter(x,y)` to `plt.plot(x,y)` , it seems that the figure is trying to plot the points (because it's obviously moving) but nothing shows up. The other thing that might help and I think it might be related to the usage of `plt.pause(0.05)` is that `plt.plot(x, y, 'o-')` results are exactly similar to `plt.scatter(x,y)`.

Answer (score 0):

To animate a plot in matplotlib  i suggest to use the `matplotlib.animation` package. Many examples can be found on the official matplotlib homepage or stackoverflow.
Here is an easy example that i often use:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line1, = ax.plot([], [], 'ro')
y=np.random.randint(-20,50,132)
x=np.arange(0,len(y))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(x, y, color='k')

def update(num, x, y, line):
    line.set_data(x[:num], y[:num])
    line.axes.axis([0, len(y), min(y), max(y)])
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, len(x), fargs=[x, y, line],
                              interval=60, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason nothing is showing up with plt.plot() is that you're missing part of the syntax - it doesn't work even without the 'pause' command. It should be:

```
plt.plot(x,y,'.')
```

However, for the dynamic updating and to avoid re-drawing separate plots for each step in the loop, you need to update the plot correctly. Try using the method here:

[pylab.ion() in python 2, matplotlib 1.1.1 and updating of the plot while the program runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12822762/pylab-ion-in-python-2-matplotlib-1-1-1-and-updating-of-the-plot-while-the-pro)