# numpy vstack throwing dimension error

Tags: python, numpy

I am monitoring the serial port and attempting to plot data in Matplotlib as it arrives. Because the data arrives at irregular intervals, I am using an approach to append data - similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944621/dynamically-updating-plot-in-matplotlib).

Here is my code:

```
data = np.zeros(shape=(1,1), dtype=[('millis',float),('temperature_Celsius',float),('relative_humidity',float),('setpoint',float),('relay_status',float)])
print data # gives a 1-row, 5-element tuple: [[(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)]]

# append the new row
# throws error regarding array dimensions
data = np.vstack(( data, [(1,2,3,4,5)] ))
```

I am having trouble getting the dimensioning right, as I get the following error:

```
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

Please help to identify the syntax error.

Running on Python 2.6, Numpy 1.8, Windows 7.

Comment: what exactly is `[(1,2,3,4,5)]`? it obviously has different dimensions than `data`, hence the error.

Comment: @nye17, no the dimension is fine. `data` is a structured array and `[(1,2,3,4,5)]` is not, hence the error.

Comment: @CTZhu I see, apparently I didn't read the comment lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Has to be the same `dtype`:

```
>>> d2=asarray([(1.,2.,3.,4.,5.)],dtype=[('millis',float),('temperature_Celsius',float),('relative_humidity',float),('setpoint',float),('relay_status',float)])
>>> d2=asarray([(1.,2.,3.,4.,5.)],dtype=data.dtype) #or this
>>> d2
array([(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0)], 
      dtype=[('millis', '<f8'), ('temperature_Celsius', '<f8'), ('relative_humidity', '<f8'), ('setpoint', '<f8'), ('relay_status', '<f8')])
>>> vstack((data,d2))
array([[(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)],
       [(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0)]], 
      dtype=[('millis', '<f8'), ('temperature_Celsius', '<f8'), ('relative_humidity', '<f8'), ('setpoint', '<f8'), ('relay_status', '<f8')])
```

Sidenote: is it for some construction project? Looks fun.

Comment: thanks, this worked. I am building a controller for a room humidifier using Arduino. For setup / debugging, I wanted to plot the humidity using Python.