# How to add/remove said a curve to/from a plot in Python with Matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, density-plot

I have a `plot` (**density plot**) from data, used as a background. I add a line or a curve over it, and need to change position of that curve with `mouse click`.

How can I do that in Python using `matplotlib`?

Building the plot take time, so I want not to `redraw` the whole **plot**, only a simple curve or a line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944621/dynamically-updating-plot-in-matplotlib). To update the curve the ydata (and xdata if different) need to be updated.

1) assign a handle to the plot with the ydata of your curve

```
self.h,=self.axes.plot(data,"-g")
```

2) update the the ydata with your handle

```
self.h.set_ydata(newdata)
```