# Matplotlib breaks while waiting for experimental data

Tags: python, matplotlib, gil

I have the following problem. I am using Python in our physics lab. The software is communicating with the lab devices, the acquired data is plotted continuously with Matplotlib in the interactive mode. This works fine as long as the acquisition times are not too long. However, when one acquisition takes e.g. 30 seconds, the program stands still for this time just waiting for a signal from the device to continue. Now, the problem is that the Matplotlib window is dead during this time and if one clicks on it it crashes.

I've been told this may be due to the Python GIL. Does anyone have an advice on how to handle this problem?

Sven

Comment: This worked for me when dealing with a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944621/dynamically-updating-plot-in-matplotlib/24272092#24272092