# Changing size of scattered points in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, cartopy

I am doing some plotting using cartopy and matplotlib, and I am producing a few images using the same set of points with a different domain size shown in each image. As my domain size gets bigger, the size of each plotted point remains fixed, so eventually as I zoom out, things get scrunched up, overlapped, and generally messy. I want to change the size of the points, and I know that I could do so by plotting them again, but I am wondering if there is a way to change their size without going through that process another time.

this is the line that I am using to plot the points:

```
plt.scatter(longs, lats, color = str(platformColors[platform]), zorder = 2, s = 8, marker = 'o')
```

and this is the line that I am using to change the domain size:

```
ax.set_extent([lon-offset, lon+offset, lat-offset, lat+offset])
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

`scatter` has the option `set_sizes`, which you can use to set a new size. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as pl
import numpy as np

x = np.random.random(10)
y = np.random.random(10)
s = np.random.random(10)*100

pl.figure()
l=pl.scatter(x,y,s=s)

s = np.random.random(10)*100
l.set_sizes(s)
```

It seems that `set_sizes` only accepts arrays, so for a constant marker size you could do something like:

```
l.set_sizes(np.ones(x.size)*100)
```

Or for a relative change, something like:

```
l.set_sizes(l.get_sizes()*2)
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter

These are the parameters that plt.scatter take and the `s` parameter is the size of the scattered point so change `s` to whatever you like, something like so

```
plt.scatter(longs, lats, color = str(platformColors[platform]), zorder = 2, s = 20, marker = 'o')
```

Comment: I'm aware of the s parameter, but that is used when you're calling the scatter function that initially plots the points. I am looking to change the size of the points once they have already been plotted using the scatter function.

Comment: Ok sorry my mistake, so you need to dynamically update the scatter points, that would involve redrawing them. Check out this post for more insight http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944621/dynamically-updating-plot-in-matplotlib