# Update continuous function in real time

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I can't figure how to plot a continuous function using Matplotlib. I got how to plot a scatterplot, but I would like a continuous plot.

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import autoscale
import matplotlib.animation as animation

import numpy


class MyPlot():
    def __init__(self):
        self.index = 0
        self.setup()

    def setup(self):
        plt.ion()
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.line = self.ax.plot([],[])
        autoscale()
        plt.show()
    def anim(self, i):
        self.line.set_ydata(i)  # update the data
        return self.line,
    def add(self, val):
        print self.index, val
        self.ax.plot(self.index, val)
        animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.anim, repeat=False)
        plt.pause(0.05)
        #if(self.index >= ntests):
        self.index+=1

if __name__== "__main__":
    import time
    from random import random
    p = MyPlot()

    for i in range(100):
        p.add(random())
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

This works, but doesn't draw anything. The plot resizes itself, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically updating plot in matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944621/dynamically-updating-plot-in-matplotlib)

Comment: fyi matplotlib is updatable but is meant for presentation-quality graphs and not really meant for real-time updated display. You may want to look at vispy http://vispy.org/

Comment: @JasonS. Normally take a look at comments kinda suck because they attempt to cover the commenter's inability to see a solution to the problem. Not so with this. Thanks for the link :)

Comment: You may want to consider switching your selected answer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'll try your answer tomorrow as soon as I get to work and  I'll eventually change the selected answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only plotting a line with a single point at a time (which doesn't exist), so nothing shows up.  If you replace `self.ax.plot` with `self.ax.scatter`, it plots correctly.

If you really want lines, you can just keep track of the last index and value and plot a line connecting the last index and value with the current index and value each time.

Add these two lines to add()

```
    self.ax.plot([self.index-1, self.index], [self.lastval, val])
    self.lastval = val
```

as well as a line initializing `self.lastval` to `numpy.nan` in setup()

Comment: Thansk for the answer! Yes as I've said in the question, I know how to plot a scatterplot. I've already thought about the single point thing, since the plot gets resized anyway. As I've said in the question, i need a continuous plot. How can I actually connect the two points? Thanks

Comment: That's great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can actually append values to a line plot in matplotlib:

```
self.line.set_xdata(numpy.append(self.line.get_xdata(), self.index))
self.line.set_ydata(numpy.append(self.line.get_ydata(), val))
```

This way, you do not have to do any of the bookkeeping yourself.

More details can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10944967/2988730