# Python plot where each X-axis value has its Y-axis value

Tags: python, plot, pyserial

I would like show plot in Python, where on X axis is position (0,1,2,3 etc.) and each X position has Y axis value of voltage from MCU via pyserial and these Y values (voltages) are changing in real time.

I searched of this type of plot, but I can´t find any examples.
Do you have someone a idea, how write Python code for this?

Thanks a lot for answer

Comment: Various libraries provide [animation support](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/gallery/index.html#animation).  I am not sure what kind of answer you expect to such a generic and broad question. I suggest giving it a go and posting specific questions if you run into a problem.

Comment: Maybe this answer could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42024817/plotting-a-continuous-stream-of-data-with-matplotlib