# Display graph of data from txt file

Tags: python, matplotlib, jquery-animate

I'm very new to Python. I'm using a Temperature sensor to read write data to a txt file. When I ran this code, it writes the temperature once, plots the graph and stops working until I close the figure.

```
import os
import glob
import datetime
import time
import csv

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import pylab
from csv import reader
from dateutil import parser

mydate = datetime.datetime.now()

os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')
base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28-051684d20cff')[0]
device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'


def read_temp_raw():
    f = open(device_file, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return lines

def read_temp():
    lines = read_temp_raw()
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(5.0)
        lines = read_temp_raw()
    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
    if equals_pos != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
        temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
        temp_f = temp_c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0

        #Write Temp data to csv file
        with open("Tempdata.txt", "a") as tempFile:
            tempFileWriter = csv.writer(tempFile)
            tempFileWriter.writerow([mydate,temp_f])

        print ("Temperature (\u2103) = ",temp_c)
        print ("Temperature (F) = ",temp_f)
        return temp_c, temp_f


while True:    
    print(read_temp())
    print ("--------------------------------------")
    fig = plt.figure("Temperature")
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    plt.title("Temperature changes over Time")
    plt.xlabel("Time/hours")
    plt.ylabel("Temperature (\u2103)")

    def animate(i):

        pullData = open("Tempdata.txt","r").read()
        dataArray = pullData.split('\n')
        time = []
        temp = []
        for eachLine in dataArray:
            if len(eachLine)>1:
                x,y = eachLine.split(',')
                time.append(parser.parse(x))
                temp.append(int(float(y)))
        ax1.clear()
        ax1.plot(time,temp)
        plt.title("Temperature changes over Time")
        plt.xlabel("Time/hours")
        plt.ylabel("Temperature (\u2103)")
        fig.autofmt_xdate()

    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
    plt.show()
    time.sleep(2)
```

I edited the codes and it's logging data, but no longer displaying the graph. I'm using the SunFounder DS18B20 Temp sensor and modifying the codes so that it logs data into a local txt file and using the data in the txt file to graph it.

```
import os
import glob
import datetime
import time
import csv

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import pylab
from csv import reader
from dateutil import parser

mydate = datetime.datetime.now()

os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')
base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28-051684d20cff')[0]
device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'


fig = plt.figure("Temperature")
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
plt.title("Temperature changes over Time")
plt.xlabel("Time/hours")
plt.ylabel("Temperature (\u2103)")


def read_temp_raw():
    f = open(device_file, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return lines

def read_temp():
    lines = read_temp_raw()
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(5.0)
        lines = read_temp_raw()
    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
    if equals_pos != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
        temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
        temp_f = temp_c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0

        #Write Temp data to csv file
        with open("Tempdata.txt", "a") as tempFile:
            tempFileWriter = csv.writer(tempFile)
            tempFileWriter.writerow([mydate,temp_f])

        print ("Temperature (\u2103) = ",temp_c)
        print ("Temperature (F) = ",temp_f)
        return temp_c, temp_f

def animation():
    def animate(i):

        pullData = open("Tempdata.txt","r").read()
        dataArray = pullData.split('\n')
        time = []
        temp = []
        for eachLine in dataArray:
            if len(eachLine)>1:
                x,y = eachLine.split(',')
                time.append(parser.parse(x))
                temp.append(int(float(y)))
        ax1.clear()
        ax1.plot(time,temp)
        plt.title("Temperature changes over Time")
        plt.xlabel("Date/Time (HH:MM)")
        plt.ylabel("Temperature (\u2103)")
        fig.autofmt_xdate()

        ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
        plt.show()
        plt.draw()
        plt.pause(0.0001)
        return ani


while True:    
    print(read_temp())
    print ("--------------------------------------")
    animation()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to update your plot live as you collect your temperature data. Probably what is happening here is that the script is waiting on `plt.show()` to complete before continuing with the `while` loop. When you close the figure, your loop should continue to run. For a solution to your question see similar questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874767/real-time-plotting-in-while-loop-with-matplotlib) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944621/dynamically-updating-plot-in-matplotlib).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [real-time plotting in while loop with matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874767/real-time-plotting-in-while-loop-with-matplotlib)

Comment: Thanks @Brian for the quick reply! I removed the last line `time.sleep(2)` and add `plt.pause(0.0001)` but it still getting hung up on the `plt.show()`

Comment: That's because you shouldn't be using `plt.show()` in this use case. Please see the links in my comments, above, for alternative solutions.

Comment: I'm very new to python is there anyway you can show me what my code would look like? thank you