# Looping figures not updating

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a ball bouncing on a vertically oscillating surface. I think the code (relating to the variables) is working however the figures are not updating to reflect the variables changing thanks to the loops. I hope it's not to vague a question but why are they not updating?

Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


    h_b=np.array([10])#initial ball height
    g=-9.8 #gravity acceleration
    #v_b=np.array([0]) 
    v_b=np.array([0.0001])#initial ball velocity
    dt=0.1 #time-step

    a=3 #amplitude of surface's movement
    f=0.2 #frequency of the oscillations
    h_s=np.array([0]) #height of the oscillating surface 
    v_s=np.array([a*2*np.pi*f]) #velocity of the oscillating surface

    r=0.9 #coefficient of restitution

    x=np.linspace(0,20,20)

    t=np.array([0]) # setting up the time array


    fig= plt.figure()
    ax1=fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
    ax2=fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
    while np.abs(h_b[-1])>0.00001 and np.abs(v_b[-1])>0.00001 :
        while h_b[-1]>h_s[-1] :
            n=len(v_b)
            ax1.clear()
            ax1.set_xlim(0,20)
            ax1.set_ylim(-a,50)
            ax1.plot(10,h_b[n-1],'.',x,np.ones(20)*h_s[n-1])
            ax2.clear()
            ax2.plot(t,h_b)
            plt.show()
            v_b=np.append(v_b,v_b[n-1]+g*dt)
            h_b=np.append(h_b,h_b[n-1]+v_b[n-1]*dt)
            h_s=np.append(h_s,a*np.sin(2*np.pi*f*n*dt))
            v_s=np.append(v_s,a*2*np.pi*f*np.cos(2*np.pi*f*n*dt))
            t=np.append(t,n*dt)
            plt.pause(0.1)
        v_b[-1]=v_s[-2]-r*(v_b[-2]-v_s[-2])
        print('%f' % v_b[-1])
        h_b[-1]=h_s[-1]+0.0001
```

Comment: You want this to update in real-time, like a video or an animation you can watch rather than plotting the trajectory of the ball over time (in a static plot) - is that correct?

Comment: You may want to refer to these questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874767/real-time-plotting-in-while-loop-with-matplotlib, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944621/dynamically-updating-plot-in-matplotlib

Comment: @combinatorist Yep that's correct. What the other answerer said worked though so all is good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not call `plt.show` in the loop. It is meant to be called only once at the end of the script. If you remove plt.show(), it'll work as expected.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion()
h_b=np.array([10])#initial ball height
g=-9.8 #gravity acceleration
#v_b=np.array([0]) 
v_b=np.array([0.0001])#initial ball velocity
dt=0.1 #time-step

a=3 #amplitude of surface's movement
f=0.2 #frequency of the oscillations
h_s=np.array([0]) #height of the oscillating surface 
v_s=np.array([a*2*np.pi*f]) #velocity of the oscillating surface

r=0.9 #coefficient of restitution

x=np.linspace(0,20,20)

t=np.array([0]) # setting up the time array


fig= plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
ax2=fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
plt.draw()

while np.abs(h_b[-1])>0.00001 and np.abs(v_b[-1])>0.00001 :

    while h_b[-1]>h_s[-1] :
        n=len(v_b)
        ax1.clear()
        ax1.set_xlim(0,20)
        ax1.set_ylim(-a,50)
        ax1.plot(10,h_b[n-1],'.',x,np.ones(20)*h_s[n-1])
        ax2.clear()
        ax2.plot(t,h_b)

        v_b=np.append(v_b,v_b[n-1]+g*dt)
        h_b=np.append(h_b,h_b[n-1]+v_b[n-1]*dt)
        h_s=np.append(h_s,a*np.sin(2*np.pi*f*n*dt))
        v_s=np.append(v_s,a*2*np.pi*f*np.cos(2*np.pi*f*n*dt))
        t=np.append(t,n*dt)
        plt.pause(0.1)
    v_b[-1]=v_s[-2]-r*(v_b[-2]-v_s[-2])
    print('%f' % v_b[-1])
    h_b[-1]=h_s[-1]+0.0001

plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```