# Matplotlib "real time" plotting in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, real-time-data

I am on python 3.7. I am trying to read data from a serial port, it would be 7 different bytes. Then I would like to plot each different byte on a different subplot. I want to read the serial port every 500ms and each time I read add the new data to the subplots. Every read is giving one more data to plot on every subplot. That's basically sensor reading.

Here is the code I have written:

from time import sleep
import serial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
f=plt.figure(1)
ax=[0 for x in range(7)]
for i in range(0,7):
    ax[i]=f.add_subplot(4,2,1+i)

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200) # Establish the connection on a specific port
counter = 0 
byte=ser.readline() #first line not to be plotted
while True:
    counter +=1
    ser.write(b'9') # send a command to the arduino
    byte=ser.read(7) #read 7 bytes back
    for i in range(0,7):
        ax[i].plot(counter, byte[i]) # Trying to plot the new values to each different subplots
    plt.pause(0.01)
    sleep(.5) # Delay for one half of a second
```

The figure is showing and the x axis and y axis are adapting to the value I want to plt but there is no data at all on the plot. If I use scatter instead of plot it works, but then it is less versatile and I can't draw te type of graph I want.
I also try to reproduce the problem without using a serial data but just displaying points of a list one after the other like that:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import sleep

f=plt.figure()
series=[[4,3,2,1],[8,7,6,5],[12,11,10,9]]
counter=0
ax=[0 for x in range(7)]

for i in range(0,3):
    ax[i]=f.add_subplot(4,2,1+i)


for j in range (0,4):
    counter=counter+1
    for i in range(0,3):
        ax[i].plot(counter,series[i][j])
    plt.pause(0.01)
    sleep(1)
```

And it is doing exactly the same thing, the final image I have on the graph is that:
[image]
Which shows axis took what I wanted to plot but did not plot anything.
The point is I do not want to clear the full plot and redraw everything because for the data sensor I will have about 30days of data to display in continuous.
What am I doing wrong with the code I have written?

**EDIT:**
After comment of  ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have tried implementing the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944621/dynamically-updating-plot-in-matplotlib). The code is then:

```
from time import sleep
import serial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

plt.ion()
f=plt.figure()
ax=[0 for x in range(7)]
lines=[0 for x in range(7)]
for i in range(0,7):
    ax[i]=f.add_subplot(4,2,1+i)
    lines[i]=ax[0].plot([],[])


def update_line(hl, new_datax, new_datay):
    hl.set_xdata(numpy.append(hl.get_xdata(), new_datax))
    hl.set_ydata(numpy.append(hl.get_ydata(), new_datay))
    plt.draw()

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200) # Establish the connection on a specific port
counter = 0 
byte=ser.readline() #first line not to be plotted
while True:
    counter +=1
    ser.write(b'9') # send a command to the arduino
    byte=ser.read(7) #read 7 bytes back
    for i in range(0,7):
        update_line(lines[i][0], counter, byte[i]) # Trying to plot the new values to each different subplots
    plt.pause(0.01)
    sleep(.5) # Delay for one half of a second
```

But it still does not show anything. I kind of guess I am missing a plot and/or clear somewhere but after trying several options can't get it to work.

Comment: You plot a line plot of a single point. But no line can be established between a point and itself, rather lines need at least two points to be a line. Of course you can add a marker to the line (marker="o") to see the points (that would be the same as a scatter). But if you really want a line, you should plot all the points.

Comment: Oh I see I understand better. Is there no way to do a line from the previous point displayed before then? Do you have to replot everything?

Comment: Well, usually you would update the line with more and more points. See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944621/dynamically-updating-plot-in-matplotlib) on how that can be done.

Comment: I tried the example given in the question you linked but it still won't display anything, I probably miss a plot and or clear at some point but struggling knowing where and what to put in the plot

Comment: Note how answers in that linked thread use `ax.relim(); ax.autoscale_view()` to scale the plot limits.

Comment: See my solution below, but also try calling `f.canvas.draw()` (aka `fig.canvas.draw()`) after you call `plt.pause(0.01)`

Comment: A side remark - since plotting could take an unpredictable amount of time, it might be a good idea to use the `multiprocessing` module and read the data in a separate process. You can then pipe collected data to the plotting process.

Answer (score 1):

As someone who worked in an optics lab and struggled to get Matplotlib to perform real-time plotting, I feel your pain *and I strongly suggest choosing something other than Matplotlib for this purpose (such as* `pyqtgraph`*).*

That said, I've gotten Matplotlib to perform some real-time plotting from sensor data. I've found it to be buggy. **Here are some thoughts** as well as a solution that uses matplotlib:

**Use dictionaries where possible.**
Why? Because accessing dictionaries is fast, and I find that a dictionary key is easier to use than a list index for these purposes.

**Use lists instead of NumPy arrays.**
Why? Because every time you resize or append a NumPy array it must be completely rewritten as a new object in memory. This is very costly. Lists can be resized and appended for negligible cost.

**The code below uses random data to simulate incoming sensor data and to make troubleshooting easier.**

**1. Imports**

```
from time import sleep
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#import serial
```

**2. Setup your matplotlib objects and data containers**

```
# specify how many points to show on the x-axis
xwidth = 10

# use real-time plotting
plt.ion()

# setup each of the subplots
ax = []
fig, ax[0:7] = plt.subplots(7, 1, sharex=False, sharey=False)

# set up each of the lines/curves to be plotted on their respective subplots
lines = {index: Axes_object.plot([],[])[0] for index, Axes_object in enumerate(ax)}

# cache background of each plot for fast re-drawing, AKA Blit
ax_bgs = {index: fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(Axes_object.bbox) 
          for index, Axes_object in enumerate(ax)}

# initial drawing of the canvas
fig.canvas.draw()

# setup variable to contain incoming serial port data
y_data = {index:[0] for index in range(len(ax))}
x_data = [-1]
```

**3. Write functions for update the plot and for updating your data containers**

```
def update_data(new_byte, ):
    x_data.append(x_data[-1] + 1)
    for i, val in enumerate(new_byte): 
        y_data[i].append(val)

def update_graph():
    for i in y_data.keys():
        # update each line object
        lines[i].set_data(x_data, y_data[i])

        # try to set new axes limits
        try:
            ax[i].set_xlim([x_data[-1] - xwidth, x_data[-1]])
            if max(y_data[i][-xwidth:]) > ax[i].get_ylim()[1]:
                new_min = min(y_data[i][-xwidth:])
                new_max = max(y_data[i][-xwidth:])
                ax[i].set_ylim([new_min-abs(new_min)*0.2, new_max+abs(new_max)*0.2])
        except:
            continue

    fig.canvas.draw()
```

**4. Finally, run the loop**

```
#ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200) # Establish the connection on a specific port
#byte=ser.readline() #first line not to be plotted


while x_data[-1] < 30:
    # ser.write(b'9') # send a command to the arduino
    # byte=ser.read(7) #read 7 bytes back
    byte = np.random.rand(7)

    update_data(byte)
    update_graph()

    sleep(.1) # Delay for an arbitrary amount of time
```

I hope that helps.