# python alternatives for adding points to a map. Driving car around

Tags: python, time, gps

I have a dataframe that contains temperature measurement and Latitude and Longitude.

I want to plot the movement of the car over time. So keep adding (and removing) points from the map. That can give some time notion of how the car was moving in the map.

Most of the python packets open-plot a map area and then add a set of points. Adding more points will force many times the replotting of the whole map (or even zooming in and out which does not help).

Can you recommend a few python packets that can plot points into a map to show this time progression that I need?

I would like to thank you in advance for your help.

Regards
Alex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically updating plot in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944621/dynamically-updating-plot-in-matplotlib)

Comment: I do not think matplotlib can plots maps. If it does I would be happy to know more about it :)

Comment: It can. Bokeh and Plotly are also good options. In general, you have you are looking "how to stream data to plot" Check this link http://www.bigendiandata.com/2017-06-27-Mapping_in_Jupyter/ also, check this one https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gallery/plotting_basemap_background.html