# How to plot graphics when the data is dynamic

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to use matplotlib to  plot graphics ,There are some differences  compared to the normal drawing, it's that the data is dynamic(the data dynamically get from network ).

a sample data flow could be like this:

```
(x1,y1,number1)

(x2,y2,number2)

(x3,y3,number3)
```

I want to plot number`i` at position (x`i`, y`i`),and the data is dynamical

I have tried to solve this problem in two ways, one way is to multi threads, I can use a thread plot and another thread receive data,  but it seems can't work. another way is to use animation, but this seems can't work also, because the data is not dynamical.

Is there any way to solve this problem？

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of [Dynamically updating plot in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944621/dynamically-updating-plot-in-matplotlib).

Comment: @jonnyg23 , it's helpful ,I've looked at it before, I've looked at it again, and with this link https://towardsdatascience.com/intro-to-dynamic-visualization-with-python-animations-and-interactive-plots-f72a7fb69245, the problem has been fixed