# How do I update a matplotlib hexbin plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, gtk

I have a `matplotlib` `hexbin` embedded in a `GTK.Window` that graphs some data (x,y). I want the `plot` to update when new data is received (via `UDP`). I am having some trouble though.

I can get it to work in several different ways, but none have been "efficient" (Meaning - redrawing the `plot` takes too long). I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098131/matplotlib-update-a-plot) and attempted to model my hexbin after the suggested answer but could not get this to work at all. I keep receiving the following error:

`TypeError: 'PolyCollection' object is not iterable.`

I'm guessing that `hexbins` cannot be update in the same way as standard `plots`.

**Sample Code:**

```
class graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.Window()
        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.window.add(self.canvas)

        self.graph = None

    def plot(self, xData, yData):
        if len(xData) > 1 and len(yData) > 1:
            self.graph, = self.ax.hexbin(self.xData, self.yData) 
            ###############################################
            ####This is where the code throws the error####

    def update(self, xData, yData):
        self.graph.set_xdata(np.append(self.graph.get_xdata(), xData))
        self.graph.set_ydata(np.append(self.graph.get_ydata(), yData))
        self.figure.canvas.draw()
```

**The code is used like this:**

```
graph = graph()
graph.plot(someXData, someYData)
# when new data is received
graph.update(newXData, newYData)
```

This is just a very small example of how I'm using the code. I don't have much experience with `matplotlib` so there is chance I could be going about this completely wrong. (which is most likely what I am doing)

So my ultimate question is - *How do you update a `matplotlib` `hexbin` plot?*

---

**Edit:** Thanks to danodonovan's answer, I altered my code and removed the ',' after `self.graph = self.ax.hexbin(...)`

The new error thrown is: `AttributeError: 'PolyCollection' object has no attribute 'set_xdata'`

Comment: If you could provide the lines above your error in your stack trace, it might help us workout what part of the code is throwing that exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that this can be done currently, `hexbin` converts list of x,y -> a collections of polygons. The `polyCollection` is just a list of verticies, edges, and face colors, I don't think it carries any semantic information about how it was generated.

The best approach is to nuke the old `hexbin` and replace it with a new one.

If you really want to be able to update in-place either use a square 2d histogram (so you can use `imshow`), or you can modify `hexbin` to return a list of patches (instead of a `polyCollection`) and keep track of the binning your self.

Comment: How would one "nuke" the old hexbin when updating an `Axes` in-place, e.g. using animation or a slider?

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
 self.graph, = self.ax.hexbin(self.xData, self.yData)
```

(if that is where your stack trace is throwing it's exception) would be because of the comma, implying that `self.ax.hexbin` is an iterable object. Changing to

```
 self.graph = self.ax.hexbin(self.xData, self.yData)
```

might stop the `TypeError exception`. Next time, provide a few more lines in the stack trace - it might help to clarify things.

Comment: That fixed that error, but now I am getting `AttributeError: 'PolyCollection' object has no attribute 'set_xdata'`. I will post more lines from the stack trace next time! I am still new to Python and don't know my way around it completely yet. So I'm not exactly sure how to easily access the stack trace.

Comment: Cool - I think your new error might warrant a new question! PS The stack trace is just the lines above the Exception line - it helps dig down to the root of the error.

Comment: I think it might warrant an edit, because my question still remains unanswered. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I know that, the question remains though "How do I update a matplotlib  hexbin?" and that is still unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your anticipated question, instead of calling `set_xdata` try something like `update_from`. I'm not promising this will work, but I would try

```
def update(self, xData, yData):
    # update your data structures
    self.xData = np.append(self.xData, xData)
    self.yData = np.append(self.yData, yData)

    # create a new hexbin - not connected to anything, with the new data
    new_hexbin = self.ax.hexbin(self.xData, self.yData)

    # update the viewed hexbin from the new one
    self.graph.update_from(new_hexbin)
    self.figure.canvas.draw()
```

Do note that without more code or explanation, this is really just guess work! The documentation for this class is [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html?highlight=polycollection#matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection) and the [`update_from`](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html?highlight=polycollection#matplotlib.collections.Collection.update_from) method is from the [parent class](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html?highlight=polycollection#matplotlib.collections.Collection).

Comment: This works, but is extremely slow. I'm beginning to think there is not an efficient way to go about this.

Comment: This seems to add new hexes every time `update_from` is called, rather than replacing the existing ones.

Comment: I ended up working around this by calling `ax.clear()` first, and entirely redrawing the axes each time (including labels, grid, etc).