# pyplot draw method for subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, iteration, subplot

I have 10 images of the digits 0-9, each with 28x28 pixels contained in an array `X` of shape `(28**2, 10)`.

I am updating `X` with new pixels within a loop and I would like to update my plot at each iteration.

Currently, my code will create 100 separate figures.

```
def plot_output(X):
    """grayscale images of the digits 0-9
    in 28x28 pixels in pyplot

    Input, X is of shape (28^2, 10)
    """
    n = X.shape[1] # number of digits
    pixels = (28,28) # pixel shape
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,n)

    # cycle through digits from 0-9
    # X input array is reshaped for each 10 digits
    # to a (28,28) vector to plot
    for i in range(n):
        wi=X[:,i] # w = weights for digit

        wi=wi.reshape(*pixels)
        ax[i].imshow(wi,cmap=plt.cm.gist_gray,
            interpolation='gaussian', aspect='equal')
        ax[i].axis('off')
        ax[i].set_title('{0:0d}'.format(i))

    plt.tick_params(axis='x', which='both', bottom='off',
        top='off', labelbottom='off')

    plt.show()

for i in range(100):
    X = init_pix() # anything that generates a (728, 10) array
    plot_output(X)
```

I have tried using `plt.draw()` and `pt.canvas.draw()` but I can't seem to implement it correctly. I have also tried `plt.clf()` which didn't work for me either.

I was able to do this fine using lines and one axis using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098131/update-a-plot-in-matplotlib) but I can't get it to work on subplots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `plt.ion()` you can make the `plt.show()` command, that is usually blocking, not block.

Then you can update the axes with `imshow`, and they'll appear in your figure as they're computed.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n=10

X = np.random.rand(28**2,n)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,n)

plt.ion()
plt.show()

for i in range(n):
    wi = X[:,1].reshape(28,28)
    ax[i].imshow(wi)

    #fig.canvas.draw()  # May be necessary, wasn't for me.

plt.ioff()  # Make sure to make plt.show() blocking again, otherwise it'll run
plt.show()  #   right through this and immediately close the window (if program exits)
```

You'll now get ugly huge empty white axes until your axes are defined, but this should get you started.

Comment: thanks! This works nicely, I took this answer with `plt.ion()` and incorporated it into my answer. I didn't find that I had to switch interactive mode on and off though

Comment: @alexmcf sorry for being unclear, [`plt.ion()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.ion) is actually what I meant by turning on on interactive mode.  `ion` presumably stands for **I**nteractive mode **ON** (note the bolding).  If you don't have to turn if off after the loop, that's interesting, because in my testing, if I didn't turn it back off, the final `plt.show()` would not block, the program would proceed, and when it ended, the plot was automatically closed.

Comment: Thanks, this was the hint I needed :) for me `fig.canvas.draw()` was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this by creating a plot class and using `.cla()` on each axis and then re-defining each with `imshow()`

```
class plot_output(object):

    def __init__(self, X):
        """grayscale images of the digits 1-9
        """
        self.X = X
        self.n = X.shape[1] # number of digits
        self.pixels = (25,25) # pixel shape
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots(1,self.n)
        plt.ion()

        # cycle through digits from 0-9
        # X input vector is reshaped for each 10 digits
        # to a (28,28) vector to plot
        self.img_obj_ar = []

        for i in range(self.n):
            wi=X[:,i] # w = weights for digit

            wi=wi.reshape(*self.pixels)
            self.ax[i].imshow(wi,cmap=plt.cm.gist_gray,
                interpolation='gaussian', aspect='equal')
            self.ax[i].axis('off')
            self.ax[i].set_title('{0:0d}'.format(i))

        plt.tick_params(\
            axis='x',          # changes apply to the x-axis
            which='both',      # both major and minor ticks are affected
            bottom='off',      # ticks along the bottom edge are off
            top='off',         # ticks along the top edge are off
            labelbottom='off')

        plt.tick_params(\
            axis='y',          # changes apply to the y-axis
            which='both',      # both major and minor ticks are affected
            left='off', 
            right='off',    # ticks along the top edge are off
            labelleft='off')

        plt.show()

    def update(self, X):

        # cycle through digits from 0-9
        # X input vector is reshaped for each 10 digits
        # to a (28,28) vector to plot
        for i in range(self.n):
            self.ax[i].cla()
            wi=X[:,i] # w = weights for digit

            wi=wi.reshape(*self.pixels)
            self.ax[i].imshow(wi,cmap=plt.cm.gist_gray,
                            interpolation='gaussian', aspect='equal')
            self.ax[i].axis('off')
            self.ax[i].set_title('{0:0d}'.format(i))

        plt.draw()
```