# How to create a function that outputs a matplotlib figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, output, figure

My aim is to create a function that outputs a figure.

If I try to call my function multiple times in a script, it only shows the figure from the first call. Only once I close the first figure, that the program creates the second and so on and so forth.

my function roughly looks like this:

```
def graphs(...,fig):
...
ax = plt.figure(fig)
...
...
plt.show
```

For the moment the function doesn't return anything, is there a way I could output the graph or at least make it so that it doesn't stop creating figures after the first one?

Comment: are you plotting something new everytime? or Is it the same graph that is updating its values?

Comment: Something new everytime. Ideally a new figure everytime the function is called, without closing the ones already created

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#coding-styles  You should write functions which take in an axes and return the new artists added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `plt.figure().canvas.draw()`. Check this thread: [How to update a plot in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098131/how-to-update-a-plot-in-matplotlib)

Your method then becomes

```
def graphs(..., fig):
    ax = plt.figure(fig)
    plt.figure().canvas.draw()
```

Finally, call `plt.show()` at the end of your loop

```
for ...:
  graphs(...., arg)
plt.show()
```

This will plot all figures in multiple windows. Beware that it will create one window per figure. Use subplots if you have huge number of images