# Can't update my plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am receiving data on my client and I have to plot them dynamically using matplotlib. I want to update my plot continuously. Here is what I tried on a simple example:

```
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

h, = plt.plot([], [])

plt.ion()
plt.show()

for i in range(0, 100):
    t = np.arange(i * 0.05, (i+1) * 0.05, 0.01)
    y = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
    h.set_xdata(np.append(h.get_xdata(), t))
    h.set_ydata(np.append(h.get_ydata(), t))
    plt.draw()
    time.sleep(0.05)
```

But nothing is plotting (neither in python2.7 nor 3), if I remove the activation of interactive mode (ion()) then I get an empty plot (show() call) but nothing is updated (the program seems to pause and don't go in the loop).

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update based on the discussion below: the original code from MarAja is working, the only problem is that the axis limits aren't being updated, so it looks as if the plot isn't being updated.

---

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098131/how-to-update-a-plot-in-matplotlib) example, it seems that you have to redraw the plot using `fig.canvas.draw()`. Also note that you either have to set an appropriate `xlim` and `ylim` to capture the entire data series, or update them every step (like I did in this example):

```
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
h, = plt.plot([], [])

plt.ion()
plt.show() 

for i in range(0, 100):
    t = np.arange(i * 0.05, (i+1) * 0.05, 0.01)
    y = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
    h.set_xdata(np.append(h.get_xdata(), t))
    h.set_ydata(np.append(h.get_ydata(), t))

    fig.canvas.draw()
    time.sleep(0.05)

    plt.xlim(0,h.get_xdata().max())
    plt.ylim(0,h.get_ydata().max())
```

Comment: Strange, I still get no plot at all (Python 2.7 or 3). Maybe my code is ok but something behind is broken.

Comment: Do normal plots work? I tried this on OS X using Python 3.4.3

Comment: Normal plot works fine. Can you try my code above and tell me if it works?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that your original code wasn't working, but that was only because the axis limits weren't being updated. If I add the `plt.xlim(..)` and `plt.ylim(..)` from my example your original version works for me. I'll update my answer (although it isn't really an answer any more....)