# Dynamically updated plots in python, how to save image at the end

Tags: python, matplotlib

### Background

With the help of the following, I have created a dynamically updating plot

[Dynamically updating plot in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944621/dynamically-updating-plot-in-matplotlib)

[Updating a plot in python's matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36863607/updating-a-plot-in-pythons-matplotlib)

[How to update a plot in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098131/how-to-update-a-plot-in-matplotlib)

### Plot code

```
plt.ion()
fig_analysis = plt.figure()
for i in range(5):
    ax = fig_analysis.add_subplot(211)    
    l1, = ax.plot(np.linspace(0, 200, simulation_time), variable_1)
    ax.set_ylabel(r'$Variable\ 1$')
    ax = fig_analysis.add_subplot(212)
    l2, = ax.plot(np.linspace(0, 200, simulation_time), variable_2)
    ax.set_ylabel(r'$Variable\ 2$')
    ax.set_xlabel(r'$years$')
    fig_analysis.canvas.draw()
    plt.pause(0.5)
```

### Behaviour

This code creates a plot and updates it. However, it closes the final plot after completion of the loop

### Question

How should I modify the code to ensure that at the end of the loop, the program doesn't close the plot window, and I can save the image as I want.

### Manual solution

One of the ways of achieving this is to manually pause the program. However, as runtime of my program is not fixed, it is difficult to implement this strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
plt.ioff()    # turn interactive mode off
plt.show()
```

at the end of the code.