# How is the function argument defined in matplotlib animation?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

Hi guys Im quite a newbie in python/matplotlib.

I am struggling to understand the following animation code on the matplotlib website. How is the ***data*** argument in the ***def update*** defined if this function is called in ***animation.FuncAnimation*** whithout specifying any ***data*** as input parameter?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(np.random.rand(10))
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)


def update(data):
    line.set_ydata(data)
    return line,


def data_gen():
    while True:
        yield np.random.rand(10)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, data_gen, interval=100)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

`data_gen` is a generator which, for each animation frame, will yield an array of 10 random values. The array returned from `data_gen` is what is passed to your `update` function as the first input argument.

If you called [`FuncAnimation`](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation) using the `fargs` kwarg, you could also pass *additional* inputs to the `update` function.

```
def update(data, scale):
    line.set_ydata(scale * data)
    return line

animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, data_gen, fargs=(100,), interval=100)
```

Comment: Thanks Suever, I was wondering... is there a way to generate animation in much easier way? Like in GNU octave when you just do consecutive calls to plot(x,y)?

Comment: @PintoDoido Yes you can. [here is a post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098131/how-to-update-a-plot-in-matplotlib) with some ways to accomplish that