# How to refresh plot in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I have some issue to do a graph and I was wondering if someone could help me please. Here is my situation :

I've got two arrays : one for temperature values and another for the time.

My goal is to do a graph representing the temperature in function of time that refresh automatically each time a value is appended in my arrays (every 0.2 seconds).

Here is a code that I tried but it didn't work at all. I'm not at my ease at all with Python and plot so sorry for all these mistakes

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import time

# My arrays are empty at the beginning
raw_temp_bme = []
temps = []

plt.ion()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
line1, = ax.plot(temps, raw_temp_bme, "r") 

plt.title("Température du BME680 en fonction du temps")
plt.xlabel("Temps en ms")
plt.ylabel("Température en °C")

start_time = time.time()

while True:
    # I append my two arrays
    raw_temp.append(round(random.uniform(15.0, 30.0), 2))
    temps.append(round(time.time() - start_time, 2))

    line1.set_xdata(temps)
    line1.set_ydata(raw_temp_bme)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Here is a screenshot of what I've got [image: screenshot of my graph]

Nothing appears in my graph.

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your data are just plotted outside the view that is not autoscaled. Minimal example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import time

# My arrays are empty at the beginning
raw_temp_bme = [30]
temps = [0]

plt.ion()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
line1, = ax.plot(temps, raw_temp_bme, "r") 

#simulating your sensor data
def get_temperature_bme680():
    x =  random.random()
    temps.append(temps[-1] + x)  
    raw_temp_bme.append(raw_temp_bme[-1] + 2 * random.random() - 1)
    if len(temps) > 50:
        temps[:] = temps[1:]
        raw_temp_bme[:] = raw_temp_bme[1:] 
    time.sleep(x)
     

while True:
    get_temperature_bme680() # my fonction to append my arrays
    line1.set_xdata(temps)
    line1.set_ydata(raw_temp_bme)
    ax.set_xlim(min(temps), max(temps))
    ax.set_ylim(min(raw_temp_bme), max(raw_temp_bme))
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
    time.sleep(0.0002)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I would have a look at matplotlib [FuncAnimation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html), though. And working with numpy arrays will make your life much easier if you intend to work with large-scale data.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the main problem is not the plotting but rather the way how you append to your lists. Try replacing `get_temperature_bme680` with the code of that function (or post the code of that function so that we don't have to guess). Also, the line `line1, = ax.plot(temps, raw_temp_bme, "r")`  probably doens't work as `raw_temp_bme` doesn't exist already.

Here is a minimal example for how to do the animation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70439692/12343828

With the updated code and printing the content of the two lists, it is clear what goes wrong: the xlim/ylim needs to be set such that the data is within the plot range. If you insert

```py
    ax.set_xlim(min(temps), max(temps))
    ax.set_ylim(min(raw_temp_bme), max(raw_temp_bme))
```

just before `fig.canvas.draw()` that should do the trick.

PS.: you also have to correct the variable name in `raw_temp.append(...)`.

Comment: I have modified get_temperature_bme680 by the code of that function. And yeah, I'm sorry, I've changed the name of raw_temp_bme just before sending the message, I've corrected it but this is not the error unfortunately

Comment: I've just added my reply to my earlier post.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FG3ya.png) `raw_temp_bme` and  `get_temperature_bme680` is the  main error you have to rewrite the program correctly
errors are shown in Jupyter Notebook in detail you HVE TO LOOK at the error given
in

Comment: Sorry, I've changed the name of my variables at the end. I corrected it, but this is not the problem I've got