# Matplotlib animation not displaying in PyCharm

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

Attempting to execute this code :

```
"""
A simple example of an animated plot
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)
line, = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))


def animate(i):
    line.set_ydata(np.sin(x + i/10.0))  # update the data
    return line,


# Init only required for blitting to give a clean slate.
def init():
    line.set_ydata(np.ma.array(x, mask=True))
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, 200), init_func=init,
                              interval=25, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

src : https://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/simple_anim.html

displays in PyCharm :

[image]

But the plot is not executed as an animation.

How to execute this plot as an animation ? Do i need to edit the PyCharm configuration for this python code ?
[image]

Comment: @Mr.T thanks for link, ive posted an answer.

Comment: You can [disable PyCharm show plots in tool window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55955602/4188683)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This code did the trick :

```
"""
A simple example of an animated plot
"""


    import matplotlib; matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.animation as animation


    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    x = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)
    line, = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))


    def animate(i):
        line.set_ydata(np.sin(x + i/10.0))  # update the data
        return line,


    # Init only required for blitting to give a clean slate.
    def init():
        line.set_ydata(np.ma.array(x, mask=True))
        return line,

    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, 20000), init_func=init,
                                  interval=25, blit=True)
    plt.show()
```

Note addition of `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use("TkAgg")`

Also, this question/answer helped somewhat : [Matplotlib animations do not work in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177074/matplotlib-animations-do-not-work-in-pycharm)

Comment: Awesome! I've been looking for the answer so long a time, my hope was fading away when I found this. :) Thx, @blue-sky!

Comment: @SungheeYun glad it helped you!

Comment: Is there a way to get it to stick within the sciview instead of popping out into it's own window?