# Drawing plot and displaying head at the same time - PyCharm

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pycharm

in the following code only the `plot` is drawn but the `head` is not printed why?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
df.set_index("id", inplace=True)
plt.plot(df)
plt.show() # this draws plof of entire df form csv
print(df.head(10)) # this does not print the first 10 rows of the dataframe
```

Comment: Not sure if understand, do you need `print(df. head())` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need assign back if want plot only first `5` rows:

```
df = df.head()
plt.plot(df)
```

Or:

```
plt.plot(df.head())
```

Pandas [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
df.head().plot()
```

---

But if want see first 5 rows use:

```
print(df. head())
```

And if want plot table with graph together use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32139644/2901002) with small change:

```
clust_data = df.head().values
```

Comment: @jazreal I have edited the question. So I want to print plot of the entire df and additionally print `head` of say 10 first rows. Now it only draws the plot.

Comment: PS When I delete the plt lines (plt.plot(df)
plt.show() ) the `head` will be printed as expected though

Comment: ok when I swithc it the `print(df.head(10))` is printed and the plot is drawn

Comment: @mCs - I think another solution is exactly what need.

Comment: Ok in Jupyter the `print(df.head(10))` and then plot works fine but in PyCharm it is not

Comment: @mCs - I dont use `pycharm`, but I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43966427/2901002), maybe help.

Answer (score 0):

In an evironment where `plt.show()` blocks the script (due to it starting an event loop), which would be the case when running this as script or from the console, you either need to

- close the figure first
- Print the values **before** showing the figure,

  ```
  plt.plot(df)
  print(df.head(10))
  plt.show()
  ```

Comment: The problem is with PyCharm `plt.plot(df)
print(df.head(10))
plt.show()
` still only draws the plot

Comment: The fact that you're using PyCharm is important, you miss to state that in the question. I think PyCharm has a lot of problems, which is why I'm not using it at all. But of course there might be a solution to it, which I'm not aware of.

Comment: Thank you I have attached this info to the topic. Can you recommend me then another reliable and efficient tool? posibly the one you are using?

Comment: I am using Spyder rutinely. I cannot recommend anything, what works for one doesn't for someone else.