# dynamic drawing chart using matplotlib with tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm making some simple application that draws chart of stock. I'm getting stock data from yahoo finance and I can't manage 'dynamic' choosing of stocks.
I'm sure that my 'generateChard' function works fine because if I get rid of choosing stocks during application running and set stock name before compiling - it works properly

```
import matplotlib

matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

import urllib
import json

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

style.use("dark_background")

LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)

f = Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
graph = f.add_subplot(111)


def bytespdate2num(fmt, encoding='utf-8'):
    strconverter = mdates.strpdate2num(fmt)

    def bytesconverter(b):
        s = b.decode(encoding)
        return strconverter(s)

    return bytesconverter


def generateChart(stock):
    graph.clear()
    stockPriceUrl = 'http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/' + stock + '/chartdata;type=quote;range=6m/csv'

    sourceCode = urllib.request.urlopen(stockPriceUrl).read().decode()

    stockData = []
    splitSource = sourceCode.split('\n')

    for line in splitSource:
        splitLine = line.split(',')
        if len(splitLine) == 6:
            if 'values' not in line and 'labels' not in line:
                stockData.append(line)

    date, closePrice, highPrice, lowPrice, openPrice, volume = np.loadtxt(stockData, delimiter=',', unpack=True,
                                                                          converters={0: bytespdate2num('%Y%m%d')})
    graph.plot_date(date, closePrice, '')


class StockAnalyser(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Stock Analyser")
        tk.Tk.minsize(self, width=350, height=200)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, StartPage2):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Pick graph stock exchange", font="LARGE_FONT")
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        stockEntry = tk.Entry(self)
        stockEntry.pack()

        button = tk.Button(self, text="next",
                           command=lambda: prepChart())
        button.pack()

        def prepChart():
            generateChart(stockEntry.get())
            controller.show_frame(StartPage2)


class StartPage2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Graph page", font="LARGE_FONT")
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button = tk.Button(self, text="back to home page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button.pack()

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        canvas.show()

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, self)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        toolbar.update()


app = StockAnalyser()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098131/how-to-update-a-plot-in-matplotlib/4098938#4098938

Comment: thanks! i managed to solve this problem with adding 'animation' function and flag that decides whether animation should be executed. Maybe it's not the best option but with flag works perfect :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by adding animation function. I created global flag - boolStartRefresingData, and set stock name also global so I could do something like this:

```
def animate(self):
    if boolStartRefreshingData==True:
        generateChart()

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(figure,animate,10)
```

I'm changing flag value to true when the button is clicked, and then I changed it to false at the end of function that draws graph