# How to detect which item in a Matplotlib PathCollection has been clicked on?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mouseevent, networkx

I can draw a directed network graph using Matplotlib. Now I want to be able to respond to mouse events so that a user can interact with the network. For example, a node could change its colour when the user clicks on it. This is just a noddy example but it illustrates the point. I'd also like to know which node (label) has been clicked on; I'm not really interested in its x,y coordinates in space.

Here's my code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PathCollection
import networkx as nx

def createDiGraph():
    G = nx.DiGraph()

    # Add nodes:
    nodes = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
    G.add_nodes_from(nodes)

    # Add edges or links between the nodes:
    edges = [('A','B'), ('B','C'), ('B', 'D'), ('D', 'E')]
    G.add_edges_from(edges)
    return G

G = createDiGraph()

# Get a layout for the nodes according to some algorithm.
pos = nx.layout.spring_layout(G, random_state=779)

node_size = 300
nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=node_size, node_color=(0,0,0.9),
                                edgecolors='black')
# nodes is a matplotlib.collections.PathCollection object
nodes.set_picker(5)
#nodes.pick('button_press_event')
#print(nodes.get_offsets())

nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, node_size=node_size, arrowstyle='->',
                                arrowsize=15, edge_color='black', width=1)

nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_color='red', font_family='arial',
                                font_size=10)

def onpick(event):
    #print(event.mouseevent)

    if isinstance(event.artist, PathCollection):
        #nodes = event.artist
        print (event.ind)

fig = plt.gcf()

# Bind our onpick() function to pick events:
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

# Hide the axes:
plt.gca().set_axis_off()
plt.show()
```

The network looks like this when plotted:

[image]

If I click with my mouse on node C for example, the program prints out `[1]`; or `[3]` for node E. Notice the index doesn't correspond to 0 for A, 1 for B, 2 for C, and so on, even though the original nodes were added to the networkx digraph in that order.

So how do I get the value 'C', when I click on node C? And how do I get hold of the object representing C in the figure so I can change its colour?

I've tried playing around with [`PathCollection.pick`](https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PathCollection.pick) but I'm not sure what to pass into it and I'm not sure that's the right method to use anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually arrived at this solution after helpful comments from @apogalacticon.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PathCollection
import networkx as nx

def createDiGraph():
    G = nx.DiGraph()

    # Add nodes:
    nodes = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
    G.add_nodes_from(nodes)

    # Add edges or links between the nodes:
    edges = [('A','B'), ('B','C'), ('B', 'D'), ('D', 'E')]
    G.add_edges_from(edges)
    return G

G = createDiGraph()

# Get a layout for the nodes according to some algorithm.
pos = nx.layout.spring_layout(G, random_state=779)

node_size = 300
nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=node_size, node_color=(0,0,0.9),
                                edgecolors='black')
# nodes is a matplotlib.collections.PathCollection object
nodes.set_picker(5)

nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, node_size=node_size, arrowstyle='->',
                                arrowsize=15, edge_color='black', width=1)

nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_color='red', font_family='arial',
                                font_size=10)

def onpick(event):

    if isinstance(event.artist, PathCollection):
        all_nodes = event.artist
        ind = event.ind[0] # event.ind is a single element array.
        this_node_name = pos.keys()[ind]
        print(this_node_name)

        # Set the colours for all the nodes, highlighting the picked node with
        # a different colour:
        colors = [(0, 0, 0.9)] * len(pos)
        colors[ind]=(0, 0.9, 0)
        all_nodes.set_facecolors(colors)

        # Update the plot to show the change:
        fig.canvas.draw() # plt.draw() also works.
        #fig.canvas.flush_events() # Not required? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4098938/1843329

fig = plt.gcf()

# Bind our onpick() function to pick events:
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

# Hide the axes:
plt.gca().set_axis_off()
plt.show()
```

When you click on a node its face colour changes to green whilst the other nodes are set to blue:

[image]

Unfortunately it seems the nodes in the network are represented by a single `matplotlib.artist.Artist` object, which happens to be a collection of paths without any artist children. This means you can't get hold of a single node as such to alter its properties. Instead you're forced to update all the nodes, just making sure the properties for the picked node - colour in this case - are different to the others.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `G` does not retain the order of your nodes when it is created, however, the order of the nodes appears to be stored in `pos`. I would recommend the following:

Add to your import statement:

```
from ast import literal_eval
```

Define `label` in `nx.draw_networkx_nodes` and create the plot within a function `update_plot` which takes `G`, `pos`, and `color` as arguments:

```
def update_plot(pos, G, colors):
    # the keys of the pos dictionary contains the labels that you are interested in
    # or label = [*pos]
    nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=node_size, node_color=colors,edgecolors='black', label=list(pos.keys()))
    # nodes is a matplotlib.collections.PathCollection object
    nodes.set_picker(5)
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, node_size=node_size, arrowstyle='->', arrowsize=15, edge_color='black', width=1)
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_color='red', font_family='arial', font_size=10)
```

Your `onpick` function should then be:

```
def onpick(event):
    if isinstance(event.artist, PathCollection):
        #index of event
        ind = event.ind[0]
        #convert the label list from a string back to a list
        label_list = literal_eval(event.artist.get_label())
        print(label_list[ind])
        colors = [(0, 0, 0.9)] * len(pos)
        colors[ind]=(0.9,0,0)
        update_plot(pos, G, colors)
```

The body of your code is then simply:

```
G = createDiGraph()
# Get a layout for the nodes according to some algorithm.
pos = nx.layout.spring_layout(G, random_state=779)

node_size = 300
colors=[(0,0,0.9)]*len(pos)
update_plot(pos, G, colors)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful because that's a good spot that `pos` holds the correct order. However your line with `draw_networkx_nodes` generates a syntax error at the `*` of `label=[*pos]`. The `label` argument is for the legend anyway, which I don't want. However now that I know `pos` has what I want I might be able to get the corresponding label now. I also still need to get hold of the graphical object representing the node that's been clicked on to change its colour. I'll play around some more...

Comment: Yes, if all I do compared to my original code is change `print (event.ind)` inside `onpick()` to `print(pos.keys()[event.ind[0]])` I can make it print out the correct label when I click on each node. So that solves half the problem...

Comment: Still struggling to see how I can get hold of a single node in the network to change its colour. It seems the PathCollection just sees the network as a collection of paths rather than as a bunch of child artist objects. `nodes_get_children()` returns an empty list! Is it not possible to get hold of an individual node so I can modify its properties? I can only think to modify the colourmap next. Or I could go back to square one and draw the network in a different way so that it is a collection of artist objects.

Comment: The use of the `label` argument can be used to create legends, but is also used to pass the label of each node to the `onpick` function, which is a bit cleaner than accessing `pos` from within the function itself. I'm not sure why `label=[*pos]` produces a syntax error for you. You could also try `label=list(pos.keys())` instead. I didn't notice the second part of your question. I will edit my answer shortly to address this.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look at this again next week hopefully; unfortunately something more important has come up in the meantime...

Comment: Many thanks for updating your answer but I'm afraid I still couldn't get it to work. The colours wouldn't update and each time I clicked on a node I would trigger 1, 2, 4, 8,... pick events. See my posted answer...