# How to prevent multiple graph plot in tkinter canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Im using function `plot_graph()` which is triggered everytime you open Graph window, my question is: How to plot graph with this function everytime on same place?

plot_graph function looks like this:

```
def plot_graph(self,event):

df_1 = self.controller.df_1
df_2 = self.controller.df_2
df_3 = self.controller.df_3
df_4 = self.controller.df_4

f = Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
a = f.add_subplot(111)
a.plot(df_1['mean'])
a.plot(df_2['mean'])
a.plot(df_3['mean'])
a.plot(df_4['mean'])
a.legend(['bsl morning', '1st expo', 'bsl noon', '2nd expo'])

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
```

And im calling this function with `self.bind("<<ShowGraph>>", self.plot_graph)`

After second call of this function program starts create second graph under first one, on and on. [Output of program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huNUk.png), as you can see on image.I want to prevent this and have only one graph. 
Thank you for help!

Comment: Why did you bind it? Why don't you just call the function normally with `self.plot_graph()`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have two choices:

1. destroy the canvas before creating a new one. See [Using tkinter -- How to clear FigureCanvasTkAgg object if exists or similar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56154065/using-tkinter-how-to-clear-figurecanvastkagg-object-if-exists-or-similar)
2. (I think this is a better method) create the figure/canvas in the init section, and reuse those objects to plot new data:

The following demonstrates option #2:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import tkinter
import numpy as np


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, frame):
        self.frame = frame
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self.frame)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.button = tkinter.Button(self.frame, text="plot", command=self.plot_graph)
        self.button.pack()

    def plot_graph(self):
        x, y = np.random.random(size=(2, 10))
        self.ax.cla()
        self.ax.plot(x, y)
        self.canvas.draw()


root = tkinter.Tk()
MyFrame = tkinter.Frame(root)
MyClass(MyFrame)
MyFrame.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Instead of clearing and replotting, it's better to create and save the line instance with `self.line, = self.ax.plot([], [])` in the initial method, and then update the data in the line with `self.line.set_data(x, y)`.

Comment: That's true, even better