# Plot window keeps opening after closing

Tags: python, matplotlib, while-loop

I'm new to coding and in the moment I'm trying to code an application which tracks a movement from a simulation and visualize the movement in the plot window.

No break command seems to work.

Here is the updated code with the suggestion of @bf-g's answer below incoorporated:

```
def handle_close(evt):
    raise SystemExit('Closed figure, exit program.')

fig = plt.figure()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('close_event', handle_close)# Definition der figure

while True:

    plt.clf() # vorherige Plots clearen

    for i in range(0, int(alpha_max), 5):
            plt.plot(Drehachse_x + Radius*np.cos((i+alpha_0)*np.pi/180), Drehachse_y + Radius*np.sin((i+alpha_0)*np.pi/180), color='red', marker='*', markersize=1)

    for i in range(0, int(alpha_max), 2):
            plt.plot(Drehachse_x + Radius_Heckklappe*np.cos((i+alpha_0+beta_0+delta)*np.pi/180), Drehachse_y + Radius_Heckklappe*np.sin((i+alpha_0+beta_0+delta)*np.pi/180), color='red', marker='*', markersize=1.5)


    alpha = "PATH"
    Schwerpunkt_x = "PATH"
    Schwerpunkt_y = "PATH"
    Spindel_Heck_x = "PATH"
    Spindel_Heck_y = "PATH"

    x=(Drehachse_x, Schwerpunkt_x)
    y=(Drehachse_y, Schwerpunkt_y)

    x1=(Spindel_Heck_x, Spindel_Karo_x)
    y1=(Spindel_Heck_y, Spindel_Karo_y)

    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.axis([3100, 3800, 600, 1400])

    plt.plot(x,y, color="blue", linewidth=2.0, linestyle="-", marker='o', label='$Heckklappe$')
    plt.plot(x1, y1, color="green", linewidth=2.0, linestyle="-", marker='o', label='$Spindel$')
    plt.plot(x_g_max, y_g_max, color="orange", linewidth=2.0, linestyle="--", marker='*', label='$Maximal$')
    plt.plot(x_g_min, y_g_min, color="red", linewidth=2.0, linestyle="--", marker='*', label='$Minimal$')

    plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.05),
               fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=5)

    plt.pause(0.001)
    plt.text(0.35, 0.5, 'Close Me!', dict(size=30))
    plt.draw()
```

It does what I want it to do, but if I try to close the plot window it just keeps opening up until I close the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while True:` will continue to do everything that's inside until the end of all days. So it's not well suited for a program flow that is to change at any point. Instead, you would want to introduce a condition that needs to be met for the loop to continue, `while condition==True:`.

In terms of code, the following just runs forever

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

phi = 0
x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)
y = np.sin(x)
line, = ax.plot(x,y)

while True:
    phi += 0.1
    y = np.sin(x+phi)
    line.set_ydata(y)

    plt.pause(0.1)
    print(f"Still running; phi={phi}")

plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```

So we need to introduce a condition at which to not continue the loop.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

phi = 0
x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)
y = np.sin(x)
line, = ax.plot(x,y)

condition = True 

def on_close(evt=None):
    global condition
    condition = False

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("close_event", on_close)

while condition:
    phi += 0.1
    y = np.sin(x+phi)
    line.set_ydata(y)

    plt.pause(0.1)
    print(f"Still running; phi={phi}")

plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```

This is rather complicated, so matplotlib has a built-in animation module to do the same inside the program's event loop.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

phi = 0
x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)
y = np.sin(x)
line, = ax.plot(x,y)

def animate(i):
    phi = i/10
    y = np.sin(x+phi)
    line.set_ydata(y)

    print(f"Still running; phi={phi}")

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate) 

plt.show()
```

Comment: This is it! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because your `plt.draw()` is inside of the while loop, and it basically opens a new window every time it iterates in the `while` loop, and to fix it, you can put the `plt.draw()` outside the loop, and then break the loop when you want to draw the graph.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer!. I want the plot window to keep updating the plot until I close it. Which break command will allow me that ?

Comment: @GanZo You can try `plt.clear()` before the `plt.plot(...)`: source from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098131/how-to-update-a-plot-in-matplotlib)

Comment: unfortunately that wasn't it

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an [event handler](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/event_handling/close_event.html). The event you need to monitor is the closing of the figure. Define the figure outside of the infinite loop and add the event handler:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def handle_close(evt):
    raise SystemExit('Closed figure, exit program.')

fig = plt.figure()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('close_event', handle_close)

while True:
    plt.text(0.35, 0.5, 'Close Me!', dict(size=30))
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Does it change something if I use "plt.schow()" instead of "plt.draw()" ?

Comment: Yeah, this is just and example. Use the plt.draw() to update your plot.

Comment: Please accept/upvote the answer if it resolved your question.

Comment: Sorry I am new to coding. I don't really know why. But it didn't change how the program operates at all. Maybe there need to be a command like plt.close(fig) ?

Comment: Yes, just indent `raise SystemExit('Closed figure, exit program.')
` correctly.

Comment: like this ? if you mean that, then it was just a mistake here not in my code

Comment: there was no error. the problem was just every time I tried to close the plot window it just kept opening up again... no error statement