# Producing a GIF of plot over time python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, gif

I am trying to produce a giF to represent the change of a plot over time in python. However, I am getting separate plots for each graph (they are not stacking on the same plot). I am fresh at coding and would appreciate any insight. The part of the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(0,t_final, dt)
x = np.linspace(dx/2, L-dx/2, n)

T1 = np.ones(n)*T0
dT1dt = np.zeros(n)

T2 = np.ones(n)*T0
dT2dt = np.zeros(n)

for j in range(1,len(t)):
  
    plt.clf()

    T1 = T1 + dT1dt*dt #T1 is an array
    T2 = T2 + dT2dt*dt #T2 is an array

    plt.figure(1)
    plt.plot(x,T1,color='blue', label='Inside')
    plt.plot(x,T2,color='red', label='Outside')
    plt.axis([0, L, 298, 920])
    plt.xlabel('Distance (m)')
    plt.ylabel('Temperature (K)')
    plt.show()
    plt.pause(0.005)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update a plot in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098131/how-to-update-a-plot-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You have omitted some important information, such as how `x`, `T1`, `T2`, `dT1dt`, `dT2dt`, `dt`, and `L` are defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `imageio` library

```
import imageio

def make_frame(t):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
    # do your stuff
    plt.savefig(f'./img/img_{t}.png', transparent=False, facecolor='white')
    plt.close()
```

then

```
for t in your_t_variable:
    make_frame(t)
```

after that, in a different script, or in the same if you prefer

```
frames = []
for t in time:
    image = imageio.v2.imread(f'./img/img_{t}.png')
    frames.append(image)
```

and then, atlast

```
imageio.mimsave('./example.gif', # output gif
                frames,          # array of input frames
                fps=5)         # optional: frames per second
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@HarshNJ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76752265/15139059) answer, I provide below an answer that avoids the step of saving the images into the disk and then reading them.

```
import imageio
import numpy as np

frames = []
for t in time_array:
    fig = plot_gif_frame(t)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    frames.append(np.array(fig.canvas.renderer._renderer))

# Save GIF
imageio.mimsave('my_animation.gif',   # output gif
                frames,      # array of input frames
                loop = 4,    # optional: loops on the final gif
                fps=5)       # optional: frames per second
```

where `plot_gif_frame(t)` would be your function to plot a given frame at time `t` and that returns a [figure](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html) object from matplotlib.pyplot.